# Problems using Composite JSF with DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

Well, i'm starting to use Composite JSF 2.0 and i have a following problem.

This is my composite:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form" />
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

And i'm trying to use this composite in this way:

```
<p:dataTable rowKey="#{cartao.id}" var="cartao"
                    value="#{cartaoCreditoMB.beans}" paginator="true"
                    emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro" rows="10"
                    id="dataTableCartoesCredito" selection="#{cartaoCreditoMB.bean}"
                    selectionMode="single">

                    <application:rowSelectUnSelect />
 </p:dataTable>
```

But i got the following error:

```
/resources/application/rowSelectUnSelect.xhtml @14,45 <p:ajax> Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines :

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form" />
```

have to be nested in a component that implements the [ClientBehaviourHolder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) interface.

Possibly, you need to nest those `<p:ajax>` inside the `<p:dataTable>` instead:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
   <p:ajax ... /> 
   ...
</p:dataTable>
```

since the [DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html) class does implement the `ClientBehaviourInterface`.

Comment: But i'm using <p:dataTable ...> in my page, as i showed in post. If i use <p:dataTable> again inside my composite i will have 2 <p:dataTable>, right ? Like this: <p:dataTable><p:dataTable>...composite...</p:dataTable></p:dataTable>

Comment: Yes. Remove the `<p:ajax>` from the composite and use it only the `<p:dataTable>` component.

Comment: Exists some way to use <p:ajax> as i desired ?

Comment: No. As I mentioned `<p:ajax>` has to be **nested** within component that implement specific interface. This is why you can't place wherever you wish.